# blackberry jquery ajax on asp net page

Tags: asp.net, jquery, mobile, blackberry-simulator

New to Mobile programming.

I'm developing a web site for mobile devices. I'm testing on emulators, and suddenly discovered that jquery ajax is not working on BlackBerry 9000 simulator with MDS.

At the beggining I thought it was "application/json" response type was the problem, but then I saw that even when I return html, it get displayed in a totally new window in the device. I tested $.support.ajax and it returns true.

For me, it is ok if it does not support ajax, as long as I can detect it in the server and decide if I should return a simple json response or the full asp net page again

Is there a way to detect this???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), it handles all those details for you.

Comment: Hi @rick-schott No, jquery mobile does not handle all the details for you, you still have to be aware of the type of the response you're sending, and in some cases, how to handle that response. BTW, my problem was due to Visual Studio saving the js files as UTF-8. I saved them as ANSI and it started to work on BB